# android activity error in activity file

Tags: android, android-activity

<

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dialog.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />


<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
android:onClick="onClick" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
i am having this error...Done lot of things but can't sort out HELP!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:id="@+id/container" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context="com.example.dialog.MainActivity" 
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

You have closed your `FrameLayout` by using `/>`. Remove the slash:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:id="@+id/container" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context="com.example.dialog.MainActivity" 
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
```